# Extend WordPress REST API with Scheme Pro Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, rest-api

I am creating a Vue app powered with WP REST API. Situation is that I have a website that has content and I added [schema pro plugin](https://wpschema.com/) for SEO enhancement. Now since I am using WP REST API, my question is how can i add json+ld schema from the plugin to extend REST API.

Answer (score -1):

The plugin should work in a way that it adds Schema automatically to the markup you write for your website, you should try hosting your website on a local environment and enabling the plugin there to see if it does indeed add Schema to the markup you wrote in Vue,

Comment: The plugin indeed works on the website but I am using REST API. How to show in rest api ?

Comment: Why do you want to show it in the Rest API?  If you write your website with it shouldn't the plugin automatically generate the markup you need? I don't see what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: I want to show the JSON-LD markup generated by the plugin in WP REST API...By default it does not..and I am wondering how can i extend my rest api with json+ld

Comment: I see, but why would you want to do that? Isn't the automatically generated schema enough? If you want to go fully custom perhaps writing your own markup would be wiser